# Unable to execute a remote python code to email-with-attachment using Paramiko from another server

Tags: python, ssh, email-attachments, paramiko, smtplib

I am on server1 where I have written a python script to execute another python script whose name is sendmail.py and which is present on server 2.

The code for the same looks like:

```
import paramiko
import smtplib
import base64

ftpServer = "servname
ftpUser   = "username"
ftpPwd    = "*****"
port = 22

try:
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(ftpServer, port, ftpUser, ftpPwd)
    print "Connection established with " + ftpServer

    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('python Codes/sendmail.py')
    client.close()
except Exception, ex:
    print "Error in sending e-mail: ", ex
```

On the other hand, the python code present on server2, sendmail.py (which I am trying to execute in the above script) is as follows:

```
# Sending mail with an attachment file 'abc.txt'
# sendmail.py

import smtplib
import base64

filename = "abc.txt"

# Read a file and encode it into base64 format
fo = open(filename, "rb")
fo = open(filename, "rb")
filecontent = fo.read()
encodedcontent = base64.b64encode(filecontent)  # base64

sender   = 'xyz@gmail.com'
receiver = 'xyz@gmail.com'

marker = "AUNIQUEMARKER"

body ="""
This is a test email sent with an attachement.
"""
# Define the main headers.
part1 = """From: xyz@gmail.com
Subject: Trial mail
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=%s
--%s
""" % (marker, marker)

# Define the message action
part2 = """Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit

%s
--%s
""" % (body,marker)

# Define the attachment section
part3 = """Content-Type: multipart/mixed; name=\"%s\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=%s

%s
--%s--
""" %(filename, filename, encodedcontent, marker)
message = part1 + part2 + part3

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receiver, message)
   print "Successfully sent email"
except Exception, ex:
   print "Error: unable to send email", ex
```

Independently, the code sendmail.py (present on server2) runs fine. But the problem is that I'm not able to execute the same from the python code through paramiko on server1. No error is thrown, just the program exits normally without mail getting sent.

> On trying to debug the same by printing at different places in the
>   code sendmail.py, I find that my code running on server1 exits after
>   getting to this line of sendmail.py:

```
fo = open(filename, "rb")
```

I don't want to read the file to my current server but instead it should sent the mail from server2, as it happens independently. 
Please help?

Thanks!